# Running only newly added portion of python script?

Tags: python

I was wondering if there is a way to run only the newly added portion of a python script?

Usually I add a few lines of codes in the end of my script but I have to run the whole script to reach them and see the results. It is very time consuming specially if I have many lines of codes above. 
Sometimes when previous results are already saved on the local hard drive by previous runs, I use triple-quoted strings not to run previous line of the script.

Is there any other method to mange this more effectively?

Comment: This looks like a question for [so] because it is pure Python rather than GIS but in IDLE you can comment out blocks of highlighted code from its menu.

Comment: If you structure your code into functions, you just call the function you want to test, rather than the whole script. See also: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/73464/753

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at this Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675442/comment-out-a-python-code-block), you'll see that it's not a good idea to use the triple quotes method to "pass over" your code. Just comment it out.

Instead of prepending a `#`, most editors offer a shortcut to double comment (`##`), so that way true comments about your code won't be removed when you undo the bulk comment. It's much faster to highlight the code you want and hit the shortcut.