# Using text editor within ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.

Using QGIS, I have a text editor that allows me to write some lines of code and quickly test them:

[image]

Is there something similar using ArcGIS?

I know I can simply write this line in the built-in Python Console (like suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/73434/87487)):

```
execfile('path_to_my_python_script')
```

but is there a direct way for doing it within ArcGIS or, in other words, without writing every time the filepath for calling an external file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Answer you link to in your Question lets you trigger external Python scripts. But, the [ArcMap Python Window](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/what-is-the-python-window-.htm) still lets you run snippets even if you don't have an existing external script yet.

> The Python window can be opened within any ArcGIS for Desktop application by clicking the Python window button [image: Python icon] on the Standard toolbar.

This is handy for quickly testing ideas and running very short scripts, but also for interacting with layers within ArcMap.

[image: example Python snippet, from Esri help site]

The closest to what you want is the [IDLE code editor which is packaged with an ArcGIS install](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/writing-python-scripts.htm), or any IDE of your choice. This saves files to disk before running them, but you just have to hit F5 to kick it off rather than typing `execfile` or similar. However, it won't interact with a layer in an MXD, and so there are some limitations over what had available in QGIS. I can see how that would be a big step down -- I also find the copy-and-paste editing process to be tedious and frustrating when I'm working within the Python window! (Almost all my scripts are now put together in IDLE.)

Comment: +1 thanks for your answer, but I'm already using it and it is not very comfortable coming from QGIS. Actually, I'm wondering if there is a way for having a text editor that is run as a whole every time (the ArcMap Python Window, instead, runs the code _line by line_, i.e. I need to copy-and-paste it every time if I want to modify something inside it): in other words, if there is a way for having a _Run_ button as in QGIS.

Comment: @mgri Shift+ Enter should allow adding additional lines before running all code. Or you can copy/paste text blocks in

Comment: @Midavalo thanks, I know this option and I will probably give up on this and use an external text editor + the `execfile` command for my purposes.

Comment: The closest to what you want is the IDLE code editor which is packaged with an ArcGIS install; it does save files to disk before running them, but you just have to hit `F5` to kick it off rather than typing `execfile` or similar. However, it won't interact with a layer in an MXD, and so has some limitations over what you seem to have had available in QGIS. I can see how that would be a big step down, I also find the copy-and-paste to be tedious and frustrating when I'm working within the Python window. (Almost all my scripts are now put together in IDLE.)

Comment: @Erica I think I will continue to use the IDLE code editor that is packaged with ArcGIS. However, it seems that there isn't a way for having the same QGIS functionality here. Your last comment should be added to the answer for the sake of clearness. Thanks for the effort.